# GreenSock, tween function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tween, gsap

I got two functions called on mouse events:

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
    var b = e.data;
    b.setPosition(b.x, b.y+5);
}

function menuBtnOut(e){
    var b = e.data;
    b.setPosition(b.x, b.y-5);
}
```

and:

```
setPosition:function(x, y) {
        if(!x) x = 0;
        if(!y) y = 0;
        this.element.css("left", x);
        this.element.css("top", y);
    }
```

element property is a jQuery object.
It is working ok but i want to animate this. How can i do this with TweenLite?
I've tried following code:

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
    TweenLite.to(e.data, 1, {top:500});
}
```

As well as this:

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
    TweenLite.to(e.data.getElement(), 1, {top:500});
}
```

and many other combinations but none of them worked.
Only on method which partially work is this:

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
    TweenLite.to(e.data, 1, {y:400, onUpdate:e.data.setPosition, onUpdateParams:[e.data.x, e.data.y]});
}
```

But it work only on fist button when I roll over and (after any time) roll out, it moves directly to given position (without tween) and then the tween goes forever giving me error each time(at least - I couldn't get any errors or anything with other attempts).

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined

at: `this.element.css("left", x);`

## Update

I figured out what is going on.
I've changed code as so:

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
    TweenLite.to(e.data, 1, {y:400, onUpdate:e.data.setPosition, onUpdateParams:[e.data.x, e.data.y], onUpdateScope:e.data});
}
```

But the problem with this is that arguments to update function which I set to e.data.y/x aren't dynamic references and always stay as those exact values from `menuBtnOver` state. So the tween works if i change setPosition function to:

```
setPosition:function(x, y) {
    if(!x) x = 0;
    if(!y) y = 0;
    this.element.css("left", this.x);
    this.element.css("top", this.y);
}
```

But obviously this is not what I want to do.
So I have option to make something like this:

```
 MenuButton.prototype = {
    setPosition:function(x, y) {
        if(!x) x = 0;
        if(!y) y = 0;
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
        this.element.css("left", x);
        this.element.css("top", y);
    },
    updatePosition:function(){
        this.element.css("left", this.x);
        this.element.css("top", this.y);
    }
}

function menuBtnOver(e){
    TweenLite.to(e.data, 1, {y:400, onUpdate:e.data.updatePosition, onUpdateScope:e.data});

}
```

Or define external update function in similar manner. The question still stays the same so is there a simple way to do this simpler. Does GS tween has any mechanic which automate this process?

Thanks to everyone for attention :)

Comment: can you create a fiddle of this? seems like an easy fix but I could be wrong.

Comment: @tahir I don't know how I can import tween library in fiddle :/

Comment: should be easy. on the right-hand side, there is an `External Resources` panel. open that and input the tween library taking from one of the links in this **[CDN link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/gsap)**.

Comment: I got this! thank you :) Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/3bf9cyw2/1/

Comment: ok so if I understand it correctly, you want to animate the button in and out with just a little slide animation, is that correct?

Comment: Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/d2g19szm/)** anywhere close to what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, in this case yes - this is what I was looking for but I'm also interested in general approach to tween properties which are only accessible through a function call. These not necessarily need to be DOM elements. Anyway thanks for help :)

Comment: That should also be doable. I am not sure why you wanted to complicate things here as it was simply a matter of tweening the object itself rather than values.

Comment: I just don't want to leave those properties public later on. The objects may be more complex and may not have defined just simple x = x formula. My expirience in js is just couple days so I'm not really sure how it's going to look like at the end. The OOP in JS just seem so weird to me...

Comment: You get used to the OOP in JS. The tricky thing here, imho, was that for a simple scenario like this, you didn't really need to approach it in such a complicated way. Anyway, let me know how I can help with any other tween related queries related to GSAP.

Comment: I don't have any problems right now but thanks, I will remember :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in setPosition is referring to that function and not the `this` of the onClick event.

you need to do pass `this` to setPosition. As in the example below, where I passed it as `self` in the function setPosition.

```
function menuBtnOver(e){
  var b = e.data;
  b.setPosition(this, b.x, b.y+5);
```

}

```
function menuBtnOut(e){
  var b = e.data;
  b.setPosition(this, b.x, b.y-5);
```

}
and:

```
setPosition:function(self, x, y) {
    if(!x) x = 0;
    if(!y) y = 0;
    self.element.css("left", x);
    self.element.css("top", y);
}
```

this always refernces the function in which is was called. as you can read about her. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

So you can pass `this` in a function as a variable.

Comment: Ok, I get that `this` points to object which called a function or DOM object in case of event. But the peviouaw code you just modified actually worked. The only problem is with the one which is using tween. Here come another qestion - If `this` points to a `div` tag then how it is working if I defined `element` in `MyButton` constructuor? Did `div` object have it's own `element` property?? Also I did change this object as you sugested `TweenLite.to(e.data, 1, {y:400, onUpdate:e.data.setPosition, onUpdateParams:[e.data.x, e.data.y], onUpdateScope:this});` and indeed the error is gone. But...

Comment: I don't know if i should be happy because it still behaves like it was before - not verry well.